# How to use Specter in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript, specter

I'm struggling to use specter (0.12.0) in cljs. I probably haven't set the ns up properly.

Running a simple example I get the following error message:

```
=> (select [:a :b] {:a {:b 42}})
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'specter' of undefined]
```

My ns looks like this:

```
(ns dummy.core
  (:require [com.rpl.specter :as s])
  (:require-macros [com.rpl.specter.macros :refer [select]]))
```

**Edit**

It actually works in the browser.

But it does not in figwheel's REPL, where I tried it first, naturally.

My `project.clj` (slightly shortened for brevity)

```
(defproject dummy "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0" :scope "provided"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.228" :scope "provided"]
                 [reagent "0.5.1"]
                 [com.rpl/specter "0.12.0"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.1"]]
  :min-lein-version "2.5.0"
  :clean-targets ^{:protect false}
    [:target-path
      [:cljsbuild :builds :app :compiler :output-dir]
      [:cljsbuild :builds :app :compiler :output-to]]

  :resource-paths ["public"]

  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src"]
                             :figwheel {:on-jsload dummy.core/fig-reload}
                             :compiler {:main dummy.core
                                        :output-to "public/js/app.js"
                                        :output-dir "public/js/out"
                                        :source-map-timestamp true
                                        :asset-path   "/js/out"
                                        :optimizations :none
                                        :pretty-print  true}}

                       :min {:source-paths ["src"]
                             :compiler {:main dummy.core
                                        :output-to "public/js/app.js"
                                        :optimizations :whitespace}}}}

  :figwheel { :http-server-root "public"
              :server-port 3449
              :nrepl-port 7002
              :nrepl-middleware ["cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl"]
              :css-dirs ["public/css"]}

  :profiles { :dev { :dependencies [[prone "1.0.2"]
                                    [lein-doo "0.1.6"]
                                    [pjstadig/humane-test-output "0.7.1"]
                                    [lein-figwheel "0.5.0-6"]
                                    [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                                    [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]]

                     :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.5.0-6"]
                               [lein-doo "0.1.6"]]

                     :doo {:build "test"}

                     :injections [(require 'pjstadig.humane-test-output)
                                  (pjstadig.humane-test-output/activate!)]}})
```

Comment: How does your `project.clj` file look like?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I had a couple of road-bumps getting Specter going in clojurescript but it seems to work fine now. The road bumps were around having to pull in the two namespaces and working out which bit of Specter was in which namespace. Nathan Marz has said he wants to [unify them eventually](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/issues/134), but until then my namespace looks like this:

```
(ns test.core
  (:require [com.rpl.specter :as sp])
  (:require-macros [com.rpl.specter.macros :refer [select setval] :as spm]))
```

So, not that dissimilar to yours! But at least it looks like you can rule out your namespace defn. This works fine for me in figwheel too, btw. I used [Devcards](https://github.com/bhauman/devcards) as a starting point via `lein new devcards test`, and used the `project.clj` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Now specter can be used as follows in Clojurescript

```
(ns test.core
  [com.rpl.specter :as s])

(def breakpoints ["320px" "600px" "1280px"])

(def styles {:padding-top ["20px" "30px" "40px" "50px"]
             :margin ["60px"]})


(s/transform [s/MAP-VALS] #(%1 0) styles)

(s/setval [s/MAP-VALS s/FIRST] s/NONE styles)
```

Comment: I recommend not aliasing specter to `s`, as this letter is [commonly used](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_getting_started) as an alias for `clojure.spec.alpha`.